# Tool or IDE for refactoring function into class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, refactoring, typescript

I am looking for a tool or IDE that can help automatically refactor JavaScript or TypeScript function into a class.

It would be nice if it can take care of `this` keyword in a safe way but is not a requirement. I can also fix remaining issues manually afterwards.

The purpose I want to use it for, is easy migration/maintenance of a legacy code.

**Example**

Before:

```
function MyService(dependency) {
    function privateMethod() {}

    function publicMethod() {
        privateMethod();
    }
    
    return {
        publicMethod,
    }
}
```

After:

```
class MyService() {
    constructor(dependency) {}

    private privateMethod() {}

    public publicMethod() {
        this.privateMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I have already found is something that can help me write it myself like jscodeshift

Comment: Other tools and libraries I found to help me write it from scrach in a worst case scenario:
vscode-refactor-by-js and ts-morph library.

Answer (score 0):

I googled your question and I found Visual Studio Code (you can see how to refactor here) -
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring

Download link -
https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: I use VSCode. Unfortunatelly it does not provide required refactoring method (to change a function into a class). Do you know any plugin supporting that?

Comment: I googled and found this -https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#:~:text=Code%20Actions%20%3D%20Quick%20Fixes%20and%20refactorings%23&text=Clicking%20on%20the%20Code%20Action,Ctrl%2BShift%2BR).

Comment: @NinadKulkarmi The linka you provided navigates to the documentation of VSCode standard functionality. Unfortunately it does not meet my requirement. :(